# Не активна кнопка на Apple устройствах

Tags: javascript

Такая проблема при нажатии на кнопку отправить заявку, всплывает окно с формой.
Но дело в том что на компютерах и на android все отлично но на  apple устройствах кнопка не работает, в строке браузера добавляется решетка в адресную строку и ничего более.

```
$(function () {
    //script for popups
    $('a.show_popup').click(function () {
        $('div.'+$(this).attr("rel")).fadeIn(200);
        $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
        $('#overlay').show().css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=50)'});
        return false;               
    }); 
    $('a.close').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(100);
        $('#overlay').remove('#overlay');
        return false;
    });


<div class="popup reg_form">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <h2>ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ</h2>
    <form id="contactForm" class="contact-form" method="post" action="contact_mailer.php">
                                    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ваше Имя*" type="text" required>
                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail*" type="email" required>
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Контактный телефон*" type="text" required>
                                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Отправить заявку" class="btn btn-danger scroll-to-id ">
                                    </div>
    </form>
```

}

```
/**********All styles popup**********/
.popup {
padding:5px 15px 15px;
position:fixed;
top:100px;
left:53.5%;
display:none;
overflow:hidden;
align-content: center;
background:#000;
text-align: center;


z-index:100;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);


}
.popup h2 {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
font:bold 16px/32px ;
color: #ffffff;
}
.popup a.close {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;


top:13px;
right:13px;
font-size: 25px;


}

/**********popup with form**********/
.reg_form {
width: 300px; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
margin: auto; 
}
.reg_form form {
margin-top:10px;
}
.reg_form label {
width:100px;
height:26px;
font:bold 12px/26px Arial, san-serif;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
*display:inline;
*zoom:1;
}

.reg_form input[type=submit] {
margin:10px 15px 0 0;
padding:3px 10px;
align-content: center;
text-align: center;




}
iframe {
margin: 10px;
width: 310px; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
margin: auto; 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Элементу в `CSS` пропишите это: `cursor: pointer` должно работать

Comment: К сожалению нет.. не работает..

Comment: можете в вопрос вставить полный код? css нужно поставить на`div`

Comment: на див который открываю конкретно ссылку на кнопку или на форму?

Comment: не открывается ссылка на форму правильно? на нее и ставте.

Comment: вставил css код формы

Comment: заработало, видит клик

Comment: можете вставить код конкретно? потому как например на android у меня тоже видит клик.